# Filter _id range in elasticsearch

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, range

I am trying to filter _id field (index not enabled) in elasticsearch by range. Is it possible? If so, how it can be done?
I've read in elasticsearch documentation that we can use 'ids' to query by _id and type, but I can't see how it can be done with range filter. (I don't want to enable index on _id).

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
        "range": {
          "_id": {
            "gt": "51f7b6b7710c42b136027581"
          }
        }
  },
  "sort": {
    "pubdate": {
      "order": "desc"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this can't be done. I have a feeling the `_id` is hashed for fast lookup, once you hash something you lose all sense of its "value". You need to store the id in the document.

Comment: Are you sure about the storage ramsey? You must index the id (which is not the case by default) as the range query matches documents with fields that have terms in the defined range.

Comment: Can you index your documents with a specified (integer) _id instead of the default _id provided by elastic?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a little late, but I try to answer and maybe the answer is still usefull for you.
Seen the comments done for collegues, I think that two main ideas can be extracted:

1. Generated id by Elasticsearch can't be used to filter or perform any operation other than GET o id search.
2. Index custom uid value is guessed (and that's the way I'd try to solve the problem)

So, I've coded an example to check if solution 2 is possible. Key parts are these:

```
#cluster node to query
es = Elasticsearch(['localhost:9200',])
records = [
    #some custom data
]
for idx,r in enumerate(records):
    _index_config = dict(index_config)
    #set Elasticsearch uid
    _index_config['_id'] = idx
    #replicate in a document field to be able to filter for
    r['id'] = idx
    kwargs['body'].append({'index' : _index_config})
    kwargs['body'].append(r)

_ = es.bulk(**kwargs)
```

Once you have indexed the `id` field, you can filter by it as you wish. `range` filter is one of them

```
elasticsearch_query = {
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "id": {
                        "gte" : 3,
                        "lt"  : 5
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see a working example in [this notebook](https://github.com/xecgr/stackoverflow_answers/blob/master/Filter%20_id%20range%20in%20elasticsearch.ipynb)

Comment: Can you please explain, what is happening in the code, it would be really helpful for me. I have seen many questions on this but so far only found your solution, that's why eagerly want to use it. Thanks :)

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur - he's reindexing the entire index adding a new property "id" which contains the "_id" propertys value. The code is in python.