# Unable to query through elasticsearch

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch in my Django application. When i try to query my result using curl i get found = false. Can someone help me here ![image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6unG.png)

I am following this tutorial and my code when i execute https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/elasticsearch-with-django-the-easy-way-909375bc16cb/  and my code fails when i execute 
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/blogpost-index/blog_post_index/1?pretty'

Comment: whic version of es u are using?

Answer (score 0):

The above method is for fetching the document by its id. As per the JSON response of the ES server, document with id 4 doesn't exist. You can possibly try to fetch all documents by using match_all query on the index to fetch all the documents and see if the document you are trying to see exists.

Here's the CURL syntax:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
'
```

Reference : [Match All Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-match-all-query.html)

You can also see the range of documents IDs to see if the document you are trying to fetch, exists.
[Range Filter for IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952873/filter-id-range-in-elasticsearch)